# How can I read files from docker container inside a flask app

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, docker-container

I am running a nginx application using docker. My nginx application creates some files in the docker container. I can see those files in the directory. I tried those files from my flask application, but I cannot since I am running my flask application in another docker container.

Is there a way to read files from a docker container inside a flask application running in localhost/docker?

Answer (score 0):

You can explore docker container's file system via;

```
docker exec -it [containerId] bash
```

also you can try docker cp.

Comment: No, I am not looking to explore the contents of the docker container. I am looking to read the files of docker container inside an application.

Comment: Here, I have created the container1 for nginx server. And I have created another container 2 for running my flask application. Now, how can I read the files in container 1 in my flask app running in container 2?